# Event delegation on SVG Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am trying to have a common click handler for all the elements I am appending to a SVG canvas. But I cannot delegate the handler to the newly created elements.

This is the code I have tried to delegate, but no luck

```
$("#floor").on('click','.drawnLine', function() {
    //#floor is the SVG Element
    //.drawnLine is the <line> element that is added dynamically
    console.log($(this).data('index'));
});
```

**Update:**
On the jQuery manual of [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) it is mentioned that

> **Note:** Delegated events do not work for SVG.

So now the question is any other workaround for this problem?

Comment: jQuery's designed for the HTML DOM, which is similar but not identical to the SVG DOM. What you're trying to do probably isn't supported. (Similarly, I needed to replace a few jQuery methods for adding/removing classes with my own SVG-compatible versions in a previous project.) Hopefully someone can suggest a nice alternative.

Comment: [http://keith-wood.name/svg.html](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, Event delegation does not work with that library either.

Comment: @Starx I'm pretty sure I remember doing something like this, though. I'll be able to check my dev environment shortly; I'll get back to you soon!

Comment: Have you tried without the selector filter (the second argument to the `on` function)? (I know jQuery has issues with SVG's className DOM object, so that might make a difference here).

Comment: @ErikDahlström, Yes I have tried like so.

Comment: It works with tag names, instead of class names. So if the exact path to target(s) of delegation is known and deterministic, it can be done by using a selector made only of tag names. I don't know your specific case, but if your lines are, say, in the second "g" element in your svg element, then "svg > g:first-child + g > line" would work.

Comment: See https://css-tricks.com/links-inline-svg-staying-target-events/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When jQuery fails with SVG you can use vanilla js. Fortunately every browser that supports svg also supports event listeners. The pure js delegated event is not so ugly:

```
$("#floor")[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // do nothing if the target does not have the class drawnLine
  if (!e.target.classList.contains("drawnLine")) return;
  console.log($(this).data('index'));
});
```

But you can also create your own function to delegate your events more cleanly.

Comment: Another option these days is `e.target.classList.contains("drawnLine")`, I'd recommend that for anything new.

Comment: Note that you can isolate the child elements you want to be the event targets by setting `pointer-events: none` on ancestors between those elements and the element to which you attach the event handler, and `pointer-events: auto` on the target elements. E.g. if your `.drawnLine` elements are within a `<g>` within an `<svg id='floor'>`, set `pointer-events` to `none` on the `<g>` and `<svg>` and to `auto` on the `.drawnLine` elements.

Answer (score 9):

**TL/DR: Attach the event listener to a non-SVG parent element.**

The note in the jQuery docs is somewhat misleading.

> Delegated events do not work for SVG.

It should probably be...

> Delegated events do not work ***when the listener is attached to*** SVG.

jQuery's event delegation does not work when the event listener is attached to an SVG element; however, if you instead attach the listener to a non-SVG parent of the SVG, event propagation works as expected and any selectors that match SVG elements will indeed trigger your event handler function.

Attaching the listener to the SVG element will ***not*** work:

```
$("#floor").on('click','.drawnLine', function() {
    console.log($(this).data('index'));
});
```

But attaching it to a parent element will work:

```
$(document.body).on('click','#floor .drawnLine', function() {
    console.log($(this).data('index'));
});
```

Note: one quirk I've noticed is that if the event target is an SVG element, the event won't bubble up all the way to `document.body` on iOS. So if you want iOS users to be able to trigger your handler function you'll need to attach your event listener to some element in between (such as the `div` element your SVG resides in).

Comment: Thanks. This is a very helpful response. I can now easily access the d3 data associated with the target element, without needing so many event handlers.