# Always trigger event when element of a class is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling, d3.js

I want to trigger an event when I click (mouseup) any element of class "circle", but I have circle elements that enter the page at multiple points.  Is there a way to set it so that all circle element on my page inherit a functionality, ie:

```
d3.selectAll('.circle').on('mouseup', function() {console.log('action')})
```

Thanks,

Comment: This may help, apparently jQuery and event delegation aren't SVG friendly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431361/event-delegation-on-svg-elements

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a couple ways:

- Any time a circle element is added, call the "rebind" function that'll take care of this. A good way to set this up in an loosely coupled manner is event subscription model.
- Attempt to use a livequery plugin that allows you to listen to element insertions: more on this in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490313/how-to-do-an-action-when-an-element-is-added-to-a-page-using-jquery)
- As a hack, you can do this on a timeout: redo the binding every few seconds.