# Click handler for SVG embedded using <object> tag

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-events

I have the following SVG with two rectangles

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg1">
 <!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <rect id="rec1" height="106" width="148" y="82" x="94" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000"/>
  <rect id="rec2" height="145" width="229" y="240" x="294" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

I am trying to a click event handler to the 'rect' elements using

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http:///code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <object data="Bild1.svg" style="width: 600px" id="mysvg"/>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document.body).on('click','#mysvg rect', function() {
                alert('click');
            });

        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

or using

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http:///code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <object data="Bild1.svg" style="width: 600px" id="mysvg"/>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        $("#mysvg")[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          // do nothing if the target does not have the class drawnLine
          console.log($(this).data('index'));
        });

        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

as described in

[Event delegation on SVG Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431361/event-delegation-on-svg-elements)

None of the code above is working..

Any insight?

Comment: The  SVG and parent are separate documents. You can't CSS select from one to another. The simplest solution would be to implement the event handler in the SVG file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it in a different way? Notice the `display="none"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg1" display="none">
<!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
<g id="rec1">
    <title>Layer 1</title>
    <rect id="rec1" height="106" width="148" y="82" x="94" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000" />
    <rect id="rec2" height="145" width="229" y="240" x="294" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000" />
</g>
```

```
<!---Somewhere in the body--->

<div>
<svg class="rec1">
    <use xlink:href="#rec1"></use>
</svg>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
  $(document.body).on('click', '.rec1', function () {
  alert('click');
  });
```

css:(I just entered a big size for testing)

```
 .rec1 {
width:1000px;
height:1000px
}
```

It works for me. I hope it helps

Comment: The object tag is as-is and the SVG is as-is. There no way for now to change the markup or the SVG markup. This has to be solved using Javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

add `onclick` event to the rect object

```
<rect id="rec1" height="106" width="148" y="82" x="94" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000" onclick='yourFunction()' />
```