# Do I add eventListener to every SVG element if I follow normal D3 way?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, dom-events

The normal way of handling onclick in d3 is

```
selection.append(element)
    .on("click", someFunction)
```

If I do it this way on 1000 svg elements, does it mean I just attached 1000 different listeners. If this is the case, is there event delegation for d3 specifically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[@AlexW answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48079776/5768908) is (partially) correct: there is no event delegation in D3, only event binding.

However, I said *partially* because it'd be better saying that *"there is no **native** method for event delegation in D3"*, since in fact it's quite ease to implement it: the <s>ugly</s> alternative to do event delegation with D3 consists in using [d3.event.target](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#event).

For instance, in this very simple demo, we bind this data...

```
var data = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
```

... to the circles inside an `<g>` element. Then, we bind an event listener to the group, and get the datum of each circle on click:

```
g.on("click", function() {
  console.log(d3.select(d3.event.target).datum())
})
```

Here is it:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var g = svg.append("g");
var data = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
var circles = g.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cy", 40)
  .attr("cx", function(_, i) {
    return 50 + 100 * i
  })
  .attr("r", 20)
  .attr("fill", "teal");

g.on("click", function() {
  console.log(d3.select(d3.event.target).datum())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

The nice thing about this approach is that, just as a jQuery event delegation, it works with elements created **after the listener** was defined. In the following demo, the red circle:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var g = svg.append("g");
var data = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
var circles = g.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cy", 40)
  .attr("cx", function(_, i) {
    return 50 + 75 * i
  })
  .attr("r", 20)
  .attr("fill", "teal");

g.on("click", function() {
  console.log(d3.select(d3.event.target).datum())
});

g.append("circle")
  .attr("cy", 40)
  .attr("cx", 275)
  .attr("r", 20)
  .attr("fill", "firebrick")
  .datum("foobar")
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

So, despite D3 not having a native, explicit method for event delegation, the solution is quite simple and straightforward.

Comment: Why would you consider this being an ugly solution? Seems pretty straightforward to me and even MDN suggests using it for [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target#Example).

Comment: @altocumulus I don't know, funnily enough it seemed a bit hacky to me when I wrote it... good to know that it's not. Also, it works with elements appended later (see my edit), just as a *"proper"* event delegation!

Comment: My answer is not partially correct.  My apologies for the semantics of the wording but it is 100% correct in saying that "D3 doesn't do event delegation".  That being said, this is a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this would add 1000 event listeners:

> Adds or removes a listener **to each selected element** for the specified
>   event typenames.

https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_on

If you have 1000+ elements, you may not want to use SVG, as the DOM gets easily bogged down with that many elements.  It may be more efficient to use a canvas, etc.

D3 doesn't do event delegation it only does event binding. So you may want to implement the delegation [using jQuery or vanilla JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431361/event-delegation-on-svg-elements/14440921#14440921), if you're still considering using SVG.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a d3 svg event delegation implementation: [d3-delegation](https://github.com/momopig/d3-delegation).
You can download the node module with: `npm i --save d3-delegation`.

[Click me](https://codesandbox.io/s/d3-delegation-vhjyv?from-embed) to the demo.